# 'Cursor' object has no attribute - In pymongo

Tags: mongodb, flask, jinja2, pymongo, flask-pymongo

Im trying to make a web app in Flask with Pymongo and a MongoDB
Im getting that it cant find the attribute password in my db under users

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    login_user = request.form['username']
    db_user = mongo.db.users.find({"username": "MattatMatt"})
    pw = db_user.password
```

I know im being an idiot, please help.
This is the database:

```
username:"MattatMatt"
password:"..."
```

If you need anything else please ask.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` returns a cursor. You likely want `find_one()` which returns a single record as a dict. As it's a dict and not an object, you will need to get the password using `db_user['password']`, e.g.

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    login_user = request.form['username']
    db_user = mongo.db.users.find_one({"username": "MattatMatt"})
    pw = db_user['password']
```